# Python return second highest value column name in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

data

```
data = [['john', 0.20, 0.0, 0.4, 0.40],['katty', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],['kent', 0.0, 0.51, 0.49, 0.0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','fruit', 'vegetable', 'softdrinks', 'icecream'])
df = df.set_index('name')
df.head()
```

desired outcome

```
data = [['john', 0.20, 0.0, 0.4, 0.40,'softdrinks','icecream'],['katty', 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,'vegetable','NaN'],['kent', 0.0, 0.51, 0.49, 0.0,'vegetable','softdrinks']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name','fruit', 'vegetable', 'softdrinks', 'icecream', 'max_no1', 'max_no2'])
df = df.set_index('name')
df.head()
```

tried idxmax which only return highest value column name, i need to locate the second highest row value column name, how to achieve this?

thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the highest and do it again?

Answer (score 1):

First set `0` to missing values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html), then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for top2 use [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html), last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) reshaped data by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.mask(df == 0).stack().groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).nlargest(2).reset_index()
df1 = df1.assign(a = df1.groupby('name').cumcount().add(1))

df = df.join(df1.pivot('name','a','level_1').add_prefix('max_no'))
print (df)
       fruit  vegetable  softdrinks  icecream     max_no1     max_no2
name                                                                 
john     0.2       0.00        0.40       0.4  softdrinks    icecream
katty    0.0       1.00        0.00       0.0   vegetable         NaN
kent     0.0       0.51        0.49       0.0   vegetable  softdrinks
```

Or solution from comment with [`DataFrame.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and again set missing values by compare with broadcasting in `numpy`:

```
df1 = df.mask(df == 0)
df['max_no1'] = df1.idxmax(axis=1)
m = df1.columns.to_numpy() == df['max_no1'].to_numpy()[:, None]
#pandas below 0.24
#m = df1.columns.values == df['max_no1'].values[:, None]
df1 = df1.mask(m)
df['max_no2'] = df1.idxmax(axis=1)
print (df)
       fruit  vegetable  softdrinks  icecream     max_no1     max_no2
name                                                                 
john     0.2       0.00        0.40       0.4  softdrinks    icecream
katty    0.0       1.00        0.00       0.0   vegetable         NaN
kent     0.0       0.51        0.49       0.0   vegetable  softdrinks
```